# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in Linux Environment but working with Windows

Tags: excel, exception, apache-poi, exception-notification

I am executing below mentioned java code with Windows system. It is working fine without any error. But i try to execute this code with Linux environment i am getting "*java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException*" error.

```
        String status = "Initialized!";
    try
    {
        String rootPath = "C:/FolderA.1/FolderA1.1.1/FolderA1.1.1A/"; /**Windows**/
        String rootPath = "/opt/FolderA/FolderA.1/FolderA1.1.1/FolderA1.1.1A/"; /**Linux**/
        
        String reportFileLocation = rootPath + File.separator + fileName;
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(reportFileLocation));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook((InputStream)excelFile);
        {
            XSSFSheet reportSheet = workbook.getSheet("Report");
            XSSFSheet formatSheet = workbook.getSheet("Format");
            if(reportSheet == null)
            {
                workbook.close();
                throw new Exception("Sheet name \"Report\" is not available! Please add \"Report\" sheet!");
            }
            if(formatSheet == null)
            {
                workbook.close();
                throw new Exception("Sheet name \"Format\" is not available! Please add \"Format\" sheet!");
            }
            /** Delete other sheets **/
            int sheetsCount = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            int s = 0;
            for( ;s < sheetsCount; s++)
            {
                String sheetName = workbook.getSheetName(s);
                if(sheetName.equals("Report") || sheetName.equals("Format"))
                {
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    workbook.removeSheetAt(s);
                    sheetsCount--;
                    s--;
                }
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(reportFileLocation);
        workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
        workbook.write((OutputStream)outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        status = "OK";
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        status = err.getMessage();
    }
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the full exception and stacktrace for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response @Gagravarr.

Got an exact error message with below code and resolved.

```
try
{
  //my logic
}
catch(Exception err)
{
    status = err.getMessage();
    status = status + err.getCause();
}
```